# How to set cleartextTrafficPermitted to true only in debug mode?

Tags: android, android-studio, networking

Currently I have the following network security config xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <!-- default config that does not allow clear test -->
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    
  <!-- trying to get debug override to change this -->
    <debug-overrides cleartextTrafficPermitted="true (DOESN'T WORK)">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

All I am trying to do is conditionally enabled global domain clear traffic during development/debug mode.

I thought I had my answer when I discovered the tag `<debug-overrides>...</debug-overrides>`. But it didn't work.

[Unfortunately according to the official documentation, that tag doesn't actually support the desired attribute.](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#debug-overrides)

Comment: By your interpretation, that tag supports nothing other than an ellipsis. IOW, I think you are taking that bit of documentation a bit too literally. If you use your network security config, does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured out how to do it using gradle runtime variables instead.

```
// In your app level gradle file `build.gradle`

android
{
    ...
    
    buildTypes
    {
        debug
        {
            resValue "string", "clear_text_config", "true"
        }
        release
        {
            resValue "string", "clear_text_config", "false"
        }
    }

    ...
}

// In your network security configuration xml

<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="@string/clear_text_config">
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

This works because gradle will automatically generate a resource file for you.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you can just source set the XML file directly. Either way you achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">xxx.xxx.xxx</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Use domain config is the better way.We don't usually use http in a formal environment.